# Image Doesn't Show in website

Tags: html, image

It seems like a simple problem. but I don't know the answer.

I developed a website, and want to show the image, but the image doesn't show? It only shows the alt text

Here is the [url](http://www.passionatedancevacation.com/) for the website.

Please notice in sidebar on the left, in the bottom of information center. There should be an image icon of facebook and twitter, but my browser doesn't show the image.

And this is the HTML tag

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/gusde.cool" target="blank">
    <img scr="/assets/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
</a>
```

What is the problem?

My Computer Spec:
Browser: Firefox 5.x
OS: Win 7

GusDe

Comment: The image IS at the location indicated. Is the `<img scr=` a simple typo? It should be `<img src=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misspelled the source in your image tag.
Your source code is currently showing this: "img scr"

It's src, not scr.

Cheers,
Ray

Comment: Wow many thank. simple problem, but i didn;t notice it. maybe i need to fix my eyes @_@

Comment: It's all good... typos are sometimes unavoidable. It just takes a fresh pair of eyes to see it. Glad to have been of some help.